# Error while trying to create an account in single user mode on OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, command-line, user-account, launchd, single-user

On OS X Mavericks, I am trying to create an account using single user mode, using the following script.

```
#! /bin/bash

# create user
dscl . -create /Users/hiddenuser
dscl . -create /Users/hiddenuser UserShell /bin/bash
dscl . -create /Users/hiddenuser RealName "Hidden User"
dscl . -create /Users/hiddenuser UniqueID "401"
dscl . -create /Users/hiddenuser PrimaryGroupID 20
dscl . -create /Users/hiddenuser NFSHomeDirectory /var/hiddenuser
dscl . -passwd /Users/hiddenuser password
```

However, when I run this script, I get 6 copies of the same error:

`/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.DirectoryServicesLocal.plist: No such file or directory`

How do I fix this? Do I need to download a new /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.DirectoryServicesLocal.plist ?

Thanks

Note: I have tried changed 401 to other values below 501, and I am getting the same result.

Comment: @MarkWright You posted a different bash script yesterday in a meanwhile deleted question. Please also include the "second half".

Comment: I assume you've executed the commands: `fsck -fy` and `mount -uw` to check the disk and then mount it with write access? You may also need to preface each command with `sudo`.

Comment: @Klanomath it is the first half that is causing the errors. Should I still post the second half?

Comment: @IconDaemon yes I did `/sbin/fsck -fy` and `mount -uw /`. I tried prepending `sudo` to each command, but I am getting the same error messages.

Comment: Does `ls -l /System/Library/LaunchDaemons` list some plists or does it give you a "No such file..." error?

Comment: Also, see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4749

Comment: @patrix I am able to list the LaunchDaemons directory, and it has a lot of com.apple.<something>'s, it seems to just be missing the DirectoryServicesLocal.plist one.

Comment: Did the user get created actually? HT4749 implies that you can ignore the error message (assuming you've started OpenDirectory first)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After starting in Single User Mode enter:

```
/sbin/fsck -fy
/sbin/mount -uw /
```

Launch opendirectoryd:

```
launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.opendirectoryd.plist
```

*/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.DirectoryServicesLocal.plist* doesn't exist anymore!

Then execute:

```
dscl . -create /Users/hiddenuser
dscl . -create /Users/hiddenuser UserShell /bin/bash
dscl . -create /Users/hiddenuser RealName "Hidden User"
dscl . -create /Users/hiddenuser UniqueID "401"
dscl . -create /Users/hiddenuser PrimaryGroupID 20
dscl . -create /Users/hiddenuser NFSHomeDirectory /var/hiddenuser
dscl . -passwd /Users/hiddenuser password
```

The commands yield errors but the user is properly created. Executing `/bin/bash /path/to/script.sh` directly after loading *opendirectoryd* didn't work for me for no apparent reason. **On a second attempt using a UID >500 it worked though!**

In **Yosemite and more recent OS X versions** creating a hidden user like this is not recommend. Instead use a free UniqueID >500 and use an additional command:

```
dscl . -create /Users/hiddenuser IsHidden 1
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36889/discussion-between-mark-wright-and-klanomath).

Comment: Just giving you a bounty - you helped me a ton, and I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: @MarkWright Thanx a lot ;-)